# Undefined Variable: rows and How to display image slider in Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

Please help me for this...I am learning CodeIgniter 3 and i got stuck on this error.

I am getting an error: 
Notice: Undefined variable: slid and Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Can anyone give me suggest to resolve this?

Controller : home.php

```html
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct(); 
  }
  
 function sliders(){
  
  $slider = $this->slider_model->get_slider();
         if ($slider){
          $data['slid'] = $slider;
         }
  $this->template->display('home',$data);
 }

}
```

Model : slider_model.php

```html
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Slider_model extends CI_Model {

 function __construct()
    {
  parent::__construct();
 }
   
    function get_slider()
    {
      $r = $this->db->get('slider');
      $data = $r->result();
   return $data;
    } 

}
```

View : home.php

```
<div id="slider" class="fixed">
  <div class="background-slider"></div>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="pattern">
      <div class="container" id="camera_1">
        <div class="camera_slider">
          <div class="spinner"></div>
          <div class="camera_wrap" id="camera_wrap_1" style="height: 465px">
            <?php foreach($slid as $r){ ?>
            <div><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?><?php echo $r->image?> " alt="Slider"></a>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is script of Js

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var camera_slider = $("#camera_wrap_1");

camera_slider.owlCarousel({
  slideSpeed: 300,
  lazyLoad: true,
  singleItem: true,
  autoPlay: 7000,
  stopOnHover: true,
  navigation: true
});

$(window).load(function() {
  $("#camera_1 .spinner").fadeOut(200);
  $("#camera_wrap_1").css("height", "auto");
}); < /script>
```

Comment: Load model before using.

Comment: I've tried it, but the result is still the same error. Could you give other suggestions??

Comment: At the very begining of the view (`home.php`) file debug variable with next code - `<?php echo '<pre>', var_dump('slid'); exit; ?>` - and check what you get and how structured. Maybe you should use/output/echo object/array in different way.

Answer (score 0):

Please try in this code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct(); 
$this->load->model('slider_model');
  }

    function sliders(){

        $slider = $this->slider_model->get_slider();
         if ($slider){
          $data['slid'] = $slider;
         }
        $this->template->display('home',$data);
    }

}
```